# Hiding columns based on name of button

Tags: excel, vba, hide, show

Tim Williams wrote this excellent script for showing and hiding rows depending on name of button. So if I name a button like "btn_5_3_H" it will hide rows 5,6,7.

My question is , how can I make this script working for hiding Columns ? Apparently Columns do no work with numbers but with letters and somehow script will not accept input like "btn_E_3_H".

```
Sub ShowHideRows()

    Dim arr

    'split the calling button name into an array
    '  (array will be zero-based)
    arr = Split(Application.Caller, "_")

    '**EDIT** check array is expected size...
    If UBound(arr) <> 3 Then Exit Sub 

    If IsNumeric(arr(1)) and IsNumeric(arr(2)) Then
        With Me  'if the code is in the sheet module, else "ActiveSheet"
            .Unprotect Password:="abc"

            'arr(1) determines start row
            'arr(2) determines # of rows
            'arr(3) determines if rows are hidden or not
            .Cells(arr(1), 1).Resize(arr(2), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (arr(3) = "H")
            .Protect Password:="abc"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got the impression that `.Cells()` doesn't work with numeric values - that isn't the issue. The issue is that you ***do*** use letters, you can't test them with `IsNumeric` and expect them to work.  This works with letter identifiers:

```
Sub ShowHideColumns()
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(Application.Caller, "_")
    If UBound(arr) <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    With Me  'if the code is in the sheet module, else "ActiveSheet"
        .Unprotect Password:="abc"
        .Cells(1, arr(1)).Resize(1, arr(2)).EntireColumn.Hidden = (arr(3) = "H")
        .Protect Password:="abc"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome

Thank you very much